# Constructor injection with JBoss Seam

Tags: java, seam

I'm new to JBoss Seam. **I'd like to know how do I instantiate a class without a no-arg constructor in JBoss Seam.**

I have to instantiate JsonPrimitive (from Google Gson framework) that has just constructors which receive arguments.

How the regular code would be:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
...
JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = new JsonPrimitive(myobject.toString())
```

Trying to transport the code to Seam:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
..
@In(create=true)
JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive
```

But this kind of thing in Seam(shown above) will not help me. **I have to pass an argument in the constructor to instantiate the class.**

How could I tell Seam to use an argument in the constructor when instantiating an object to be injected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the factory annotation:

```
@Factory("jsonPrimitive")
public void loadJsonPrimitive()
{
    jsonPrimitive = new JsonPrimitive(myobject.toString())
}
```

See the Seam documentation for [@Factory](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e4345)